# One Control for Multiple Experiments in A/B testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Our company does lots of A/B testing experiments. To save time, they would like to use one control group for two experiments, instead of two control groups, one for each experiment. The experiments are binary and we are looking at the difference between proportions.

I'm not comfortable with the idea of using the same control group for both experiments as this would introduce the dependence between the experiments. For example, let's say we run two experiments with the same control group, then if we sample by chance an extreme control group, we are very likely to observe p-value < 0.05 in both experiments. If we sampled different control groups for each experiment, it is less likely that both would have p-value < 0.05 due to extreme sample of a control.

The number of false positives over a large number of experiments is still the same as if we had different control groups, it's just that these false positives are happening dependently.

It is not completely clear to me, how bad of a problem is this? It is possible that we would run 5 experiments at the same time. That being said if we think that p-value is 0.05, and in reality, it is 0.07, we are OK with that (but not let's say 0.12), but I would like to have some quantitive idea how bad is this, given that it is bad at all.

EDIT: To give a concrete example, let's say that we run 200 experiments over year, and we do it in batches of 5, where each of 5 gets the same control, we use p-value < 0.05 for rejecting the H0. Let's say that the cost associated with rejecting the H0 given it is true is the same over all the experiments. Would our cost be the same over all the experiments if we used 1 control group over 5 experiments vs 5 control groups for batch of 5 experiments?

Comment: You can simulate this process on your current data and check how often you would reject the null. You can also do a balance check on your actual test groups each time to make sure you don't get a weird split.

Comment: I run the experiment. Apart from p-values being correlated in one batch, it doesn't seem to make a difference.